# Apache httpd - OCSP-Stapling - ssl:error AH02217

Tags: apache, ssl, ssl-certificate, httpd.conf, ocsp

### Introduction

I want to configure [OCSP Stapling](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/OCSPStapling) for my `httpd` service, which is running in this version:

```
[root@localhost ~]# httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
Server built:   Nov 19 2015 21:43:13
```

I am running this Linux distribution:

```
[root@localhost ~]# lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch:cxx-4.1-amd64:cxx-4.1-noarch:desktop-4.1-amd64:desktop-4.1-noarch:languages-4.1-amd64:languages-4.1-noarch:printing-4.1-amd64:printing-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)
Release:        7.2.1511
Codename:       Core
```

### Approach

From what I understood by reading the [official Apache ssl HowTo](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/ssl/ssl_howto.html) and the [official Apache ssl Doc](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslcacertificatefile) is: On the one hand I have to edit the file `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`, and on the other I have to specify and copy a `.pem` file. A similar approach is given by a [Tutorial found here](https://support.globalsign.com/customer/portal/articles/1642333-apache---enable-ocsp-stapling).

### Problem implementing Approach

As a matter of fact my file `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` contains several `VirtualHosts` and looks like this (comments and some other things are omited):

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"
Listen 8443
ServerName my.main.domain.com
LoadModule  proxy_module         modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule  proxy_http_module    modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule  headers_module       modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule  deflate_module       modules/mod_deflate.so
LoadFile    /usr/lib64/libxml2.so.2
LoadModule  xml2enc_module       modules/mod_xml2enc.so
LoadModule  proxy_html_module    modules/mod_proxy_html.so
LoadModule  ssl_module           /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_ssl.so
Include conf.modules.d/*.conf
SSLUseStapling On
SSLStaplingCache "shmcb:logs/ssl_stapling(32768)"
#commenting this in leads to the errors `AH02217`, `AH02235`,`AH01895` and `AH02312` from which httpd refused to restart
#SSLCACertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf/myFile.pem
<VirtualHost *:8443>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ServerName sub1.my.main.domain.com
    RewriteEngine On
    ProxyVia Off
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8887/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8887/
    RequestHeader add X-Forwarded-Ssl on
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf/someOtherFile.cer
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/conf/someOtherFile.key
    #commenting this in here also leads to the errors `AH02217`, `AH02235`,`AH01895` and `AH02312` from which httpd refused to restart
    #SSLCACertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf/myFile.pem
</VirtualHost>
# more VirtualHost directives
```

This is the content of the error log file `/etc/httpd/logs/error_log`:

```
[Wed Apr 06 11:23:01.702030 2016] [ssl:error] [pid 19305] AH02217: ssl_stapling_init_cert: Can't retrieve issuer certificate!
[Wed Apr 06 11:23:01.702050 2016] [ssl:error] [pid 19305] AH02235: Unable to configure server certificate for stapling
[Wed Apr 06 11:23:01.702639 2016] [ssl:emerg] [pid 19305] AH01895: Unable to configure verify locations for client authentication
[Wed Apr 06 11:23:01.702650 2016] [ssl:emerg] [pid 19305] AH02312: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting.
```

I have produced the file `myFile.pem` from a `anotherFile.pfx` using `openssl` in the following fashion:

```
[root@localhost ~]# openssl pkcs12 -in anotherFile.pfx -nocerts -out myFile.pem
Enter Import Password:
MAC verified OK
```

### Questions

1. What is wrong with my config?
2. Did I do something wrong when converting the `.pfx` file to the `.pem` file?
3. Which information do I need from my certificate providers to correctly convert the `.pfx` file to the `.pem` file?
4. Is my description lacking information crucial to debug this problem?